# What's this part on the inner part of the wing on a Cessna 152 - opposite of the thermometer?

Tags: cessna

[image]

Trying to figure out what this part is.  Sorry for the dark pic, was simming in bad weather.

Answer (score 15):

It's an air vent on the left side. There is another air vent on the right side, which also contains a temperature gauge.

(image from this source: [X-PlaneReviews](https://xplanereviews.com/index.php?/forums/topic/785-aircraft-review-cessna-152-ll-by-justflight-thranda/))

[image]

It can also be a hiding place for bees to hang out. So it's a good idea to open the vents on the ground before takeoff to possibly prevent an airborne surprise!

Comment: @757toga Had that happen to me once in the air during flight training. My instructor grabbed his jacket off the back seat and precisely killed the bee with a quick flick.